# Plot several plots together as subplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I try to plot several plots with multiple data series as subplots.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],
    'index':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
    '02K W':[3.5, 0.1, 3, 'nan', 0.2], 
    '03K W':[4.2, 5.2, 2.5, 3.0, 0.6], 
    '04K W':[1.5, 2.6, 8.2, 4.2, 5.3]}) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],
    'index':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
    '02K W':[3, 'nan', 5, 3, 5.2], 
    '03K W':[2.1, 2.9, 2.5, 3.9, 6.7], 
    '04K W':[1.8, 6.2, 5, 2.5, 3.7]}) 

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df1 = df1.set_index('index')

for col in df1.columns[1:]:
    plt.plot(df1['Date'], df1[col])
```

At the moment, I can only plot the first plot and I am not sure how I need to assign the `for loop` to the y-axis.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.plot(df1['Date'], y)
ax2.plot(df2['Date'], y)
```

Thanks a lot for the advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
for col in df1.columns[1:]:
    ax1.plot(df1['Date'], df1[col])
    ax2.plot(df2['Date'], df2[col])
```

Answer (score 1):

Something you can do in order to avoid having to use the axis syntax is call `plt.sca(ax)` which sets the current axis to `ax`. This is quite neat because you can explicitly set the axis you want to work with.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
plt.sca(ax1)
plt.plot.plot(df1['Date'], y)
plt.sca(ax2)
plt.plot(df2['Date'], y)
```

There are many ways to navigate matplotlib and I find the above mentioned approach intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to iterate across all the columns. Instead, parse them all directly. Look at this:

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],
    'index':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
    '02K W':[3.5, 0.1, 3, 'nan', 0.2], 
    '03K W':[4.2, 5.2, 2.5, 3.0, 0.6], 
    '04K W':[1.5, 2.6, 8.2, 4.2, 5.3]}) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],
    'index':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
    '02K W':[3, 'nan', 5, 3, 5.2], 
    '03K W':[2.1, 2.9, 2.5, 3.9, 6.7], 
    '04K W':[1.8, 6.2, 5, 2.5, 3.7]}) 

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df1 = df1.set_index('index')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2 = df2.set_index('index')

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(25,8))
plot1 = ax1.plot(df1['Date'], df1[df1.columns[1:]])
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('W')
plot2 = ax2.plot(df2['Date'], df2[df2.columns[1:]])
ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
ax2.set_ylabel('W')

ax1.legend(plot1, df1.columns[1:])
ax2.legend(plot2, df2.columns[1:])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this alternative approach!